# Cannot add any apps to Security & Privacy preferences on Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, security, preferences, accessibility

I recently updated my Mac to Mojave.

I have several apps (e.g. Dropbox, Backblaze, Stay) that require specific permissions that can be granted via System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy.

Since the update to Mojave, I can no longer add any apps to the mentioned Preferences pane. For example, when going to the "Accessibility pane ("Allow the apps below to control your computer") and adding an app via the `+` button or by drag & drop from the Finder, the action is simply ignored and the list stays empty.

Any idea to work around it?

[image: Screenshot of the empty list]

Comment: Backblaze needs v5.4.0 - you should have had an email about it from them. The others, idk.

Comment: did you try to disable the SIP ?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. As you said, they did email me and I do have 5.4.0 installed.

Comment: @Buscar웃 that seems a bit drastic to me and I'd do it only as a last resort, since it decreases security.

Comment: Hi @Gavrie! Have you tried `tccutil reset All` in Terminal? I have seen some references to that as a way to "reset" these permissions, although there seems to be some discussion as to whether "All" still works or not (the man page only says that it can do things like ` tccutil reset AddressBook` and does not mention `All` directly. I hope you get it working!

Comment: I had the same issue. I left the dialog open for a few minutes while researching and it eventually populated with the expected list of apps; after that I was able to interact with the window normally.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer this but since this question blocked me from months, I feel a civic duty to share my solution. I had disabled SIP to do something else a few months ago. Turns out disabling SIP not only lifts a few restrictions, it also stops many permission dialogs from popping up at all even if the permissions are actively enforced. This affects Calendar and Screen Recording a least. Enabled sip solved it immediately. Apps appeared in those lists and worked properly. Resetting TCC, deleting tcc.db, etc did not work for me.

Comment: I do not have a plus sign to add apps to my microphone in settings -> security. I want to enable the micro. Strange Apple, I cannot understand this concern to block micro per default.

Answer (score 3):

Removing `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` file and restarting the system solved the problem.

In addition you probably have to restart in recovery mode and do a `csrutil disable`.

Then you can reboot and delete the file.  Don't forget to `csrutil enable` in recover mode after it's done. And reboot again to use the system.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue reappeared after a few days. Coupled with random freezes now. I really hope Apple is gonna fix this soon..

Comment: This worked for me the file that needed to be removed was under the user directory, not global: `~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC`.

Comment: Worked for me. I hope the problem doesn't reappear in a few days. This was driving me insane.

Comment: if I `rm` the `tcc.db` file I get `override rw-r--r-- root/wheel restricted for /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db?` and get Operation not permitted as sudo.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up uninstalling Backblaze completely (even though it was the up-to-date version 5.4.0 that supports Mojave) and then reinstalled the same version from scratch.

This took care of the issue.

Comment: What is Backblaze, is it a standard and therefore default on Mac Mini? I have Monterey installed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my per-user `tccd` was disabled somehow.

- Open Terminal.app, and run `launchctl list | grep -I com.apple.tccd`
- If no matches are found, re-enable your user `tccd` using

  ```
  launchctl load -wF  /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.tccd.plist
  ```

Comment: I get `com.apple.tccd` as result to `launchctl list` so am safe here.

Comment: I had two tccd processes running.  I went into Activity Monitor, located both, force quit both, and everything seems to be running fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem which was in my case caused by ESET. Now after I uninstalled ESET I am able to see list of apps in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy.

But whenever I add or delete app from the list my Mac strangely freezes like I can move cursor but I am unable to click on anything until restart.

Comment: Had this same error. As @Forest suggested, uninstalling ESET did the trick. (But I didn't have the same freezing error as @Forest.)

Comment: I suppose that Eset is not the default virus programme, but a common one for Mac to install.